# Stripe Payment Element and one page checkout - what is the correct payment flow?

Tags: javascript, php, json, stripe-payments

I want to upgrade my simple Stripe one-page checkout to use the new Payment Element that unifies a lot of different payment methods under one component. By simple I mean, the customer chooses between a few variants of one product, provides needed info and submits the order. Collect money, send emails, fulfil the order etc. Just vanilla `HTML/CSS/JS` and a  bit of `PHP`. Using `Payment Intents API` to process the payments, was on `Charges API` before.

I love the premise of this unified element so I decided to give it a go. It turns out I have trouble understanding what to do with both `stripe.confirmPayment` method and `return_url` parameter.

I guess the `return_url` should be my checkout page? Also, is there a way to redirect without hard refresh? Ideally, I would be able to do some server-side stuff before redirect happens, but it seems that `stripe.confirmPayment` automatically redirects if resolved successfully.

Here is my code. I am a designer btw, so guess I am missing something obvious as always.

```
        // init Stripe elements
        fetch('/config.php', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((response) => {
        return setupElements(response.publishableKey)
    })

var setupElements = function (publishableKey) {
    stripe = Stripe(publishableKey);
    // create payment intent to setup payment element
    fetch('/setup-elements.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(order)
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            const appearance = {
            theme: 'none',
            labels: 'floating',
            // etc.....
            };
            elements = stripe.elements({
                clientSecret: data.clientSecret,
                fonts: [{
                    cssSrc: 'https://use.typekit.net/hly2qug.css'
                }, ],
                appearance
            });
            const paymentElement = elements.create("payment", {
                fields: {
                    billingDetails: {
                        email: 'never',
                        address: {
                            line1: 'never',
                            city: 'never',
                            state: 'never',
                            country: 'never',
                            postalCode: 'never'
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");
          
        })
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isFormValid = validate.validateAll(form);
    if (isFormValid.length < 1) {
        loading(true);
        collectFormInfo();
        confirmPayment();
    }
})

var confirmPayment = function () {
    stripe.confirmPayment({
            elements,
            confirmParams: {
                return_url: 'checkout-page?',
                payment_method_data: {
                    billing_details: {
                        email: order.customer.email,
                        address: {
                            line1: order.delivery.address,
                            city: order.delivery.city,
                            state: order.delivery.state,
                            country: order.delivery.country,
                            postal_code: order.delivery.postcode
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            // This is where I get stuck. How to do stuff after 
            // payment is confirmed
            // and not get redirected immediately? If 
            //redirected, where to and is it 
            // possible to do so asynchronously?    
            if (result.error.type === "card_error" || result.error.type === "validation_error") {
                showMessage(result.error.message);
            } else {
                // get client secret
                const clientSecret = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
                    "payment_intent_client_secret"
                );
                // bail if no client secret
                if (!clientSecret) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    stripe.retrievePaymentIntent(clientSecret).then(function (response) {
                        switch (response.paymentIntent.status) {
                            case "succeeded":
                                showMessage("Payment succeeded!");
                                break;
                            case "processing":
                                showMessage("Your payment is processing.");
                                break;
                            case "requires_payment_method":
                                showMessage("Payment failed. Please try another payment method.");
                                break;
                            default:
                                showMessage("Something went wrong.");
                                break;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        })
}
```

Nudge in the right direction is all I need, at least I hope so

Answer (score 0):

Yes the `return_url` should be your own page that Stripe will automatically redirect after your customer completed the Payment: [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements#web-submit-payment). 'checkout-page?' doesn't look like a valid URL. Normally you would want something like 'http://localhost:4242/success'

This action is done automatically on client and you can't intercept it. Any action you want to perform on server should be handled via webhook, at Step 6 "Handle post-payment events" at the same article above.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up. I was hoping there is a way to intercept the redirect. One thing is still not clear to me. Where does the part that retrieves the payment intent and check statuses go? That code should be placed on the redirected page, right? I am not using async/await as per docs, is that a problem?

Comment: Yes that code should be put on the redirected page. And I don't think not using async/await would be a problem